# Why won't some pictures on my website show up in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

In my lovely new website, some of the photos are not showing up in IE(7).

Here's the URL: http://highroadnewmexico.com/tour-artists.html

All the artists should have photos, but some appear collapsed into horizontal lines.

I've tried everything I could find on the Web...  Help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You need to get rid of the "height: auto" lines, because of the way IE interprets it.

```
<img width="110" height="auto" class="Right" alt="sample art" src="art_pics/02-Cent.jpg"/>
```

You should read http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_height.asp

The height attribute only has pixels and '%' attributes, so using 'auto' will not work.

```
pixels   The height in pixels (like "100px" or just "100")
percent  The height in percent of the containing element (like "20%")
```

May I suggest using this free HTML validation service. It's not perfect, but it will let you know if there are any glaring erros with your code, in terms of adhering to standards and what not. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Doh! Thought I'd gotten rid of all those. Haven't been getting enough sleep...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It can happend if you are using jpegs with cmyk format instead of rgba.